# How do I change the IP address of ubuntu(16.x) machine on oracle virtual box(5.0.20)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, hadoop

I'm trying to setup a hadoop multi node cluster on Ubuntu 16.x with oracle virtual box(5.0.20). As part of the setup I want to change the IP address of one Ubuntu machine.

But the problem is, there are two interfaces (enp0s3, enp0s8) in the master Ubuntu machine.

**Configuration of master Ubuntu machine**:

**`ifconfig`**

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6f:64:6a  
          inet addr:192.168.xx.XXX  Bcast:192.168.XX.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: aaa::bbbb:c995:acbb:eef1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8731 (8.7 KB)  TX bytes:6886 (6.8 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ff:7d:b3  
          inet addr:10.0.3.xx  Bcast:10.0.3.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3b9b:103:dc67:1375/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3173 (3.1 KB)  TX bytes:8427 (8.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3875 (3.8 KB)  TX bytes:3875 (3.8 KB)
```

**`netstat -r`**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.0.x.x        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s8
10.0.x.x        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s8
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp0s8
192.168.56.x    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s3
```

So if want to change the static IP address I need to go to `/etc/network/interfaces` and add a block which looks like:

```
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.0.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4.
```

But I don't know for which interface (`enp0s3` or `enp0s8`) I should change the IP address, and how I can find the remaining values (`gateway` and `dns-nameservers`).